# replace strings in unequal nested lists

Tags: python, string, list, nested-lists

I have an unequal nested list containing strings.

```
newlist=[['realoldbone', 'thenewhouse', 'oldking'],
         ['softhat', 'hatoldhat'],
         ['shirt', 'sweatshirt', 'myoldShirt']]
```

For two features say,

```
Features=["old","new"]
```

if the element in `newlist` contains an element of `Features`, I want to replace it with that element of `Features`. So, the final answer will be like this:

```
newlist=[['old', 'new', 'old'],
     ['softhat', 'old'],
     ['shirt', 'sweatshirt', 'old']]
```

I can't think of a way how I can achieve this. I tried using  `for j in i for i in newlist` type of loops along with string matching but to no avail. So,
I appreciate your  suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest case would be to loop through the lists and modify if feature exists:

```
for feature in Features:
    for lst in newlist:
        for i, item in enumerate(lst):
            if feature in item:
                lst[i] = feature
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[['old', 'new', 'old'], ['softhat', 'old'], ['shirt', 'sweatshirt', 'old']]
```